# How to set an image's alt-text with pandoc for docx conversion to Jats

Tags: xml, image, docx, pandoc

I am converting a docx file into Jats XML and Markdown using option --extract-media (stored images in media folder and name these as image1, image2...). I want the conversion in Jats to look like this:

```
<p>My image folder

   **<inline-graphic xlink:href="images/image1.jpg">**

     <alt-text>McDuck logo</alt-text>

   </inline-graphic> first initiated these far-flung programs in 005...

</p> ....
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this using Pandoc or if Pandoc does not support generating alt-text from docx to Jats. I need help. Thanks in advanc

Ofuuzo

Answer (score 0):

I tried with LibreOffice, but wasn't able to make this work.

Looking at the code, I see that pandoc looks for a `<docPr>` element within an `<inline>` element and then uses the `descr` attribute of that `<docPr>` element as alt text. However, at least LibreOffice either added the `<docPr>` in a different location in the the XML, or, if it *did* add that element, LibreOffice wouldn't set the `descr` attribute.

Please raise an issue for this at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues and attach a file with the "alternative text" property of an image set, so we can see how Word handles this.